# Can I create a JFrame with multiple images?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe

Here is my problem:

I have an application that every iteration it returns to me a list of images. The imagens have different sizes and the number of images to be shown varies every time.

Is there a way to show in a jFrame all the images without knowing the number of jPanels to create? Is there an easy way to do that?

Obs.: The images should be shown at same time, like side by side, or listed, because they are used for comparisson purposes.

Obs.2: The number of images to be shown is around 20-60 for each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I assume that you are able to show images in a `JPanel`. In that case, you can keep a list of `JPanels` and dynamically update this list. Of course, the layout to be drawn on the `JFrame` is completely up to you, but for a job like this one, you might want to use [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

To keep a list of JPanels:

```
ArrayList<JPanel> panelList = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
...
panelList.add(new JPanel());
...
panelList.clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

As you want to see all your images in the same Panel, I suggest you use a [TreeMap Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) to display your panels using the dimension of your image as the weight of each image. And then, resize each image so it can fit in each panel.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://27.media.tumblr.com/NngfN9gsDqq8kydsfeAglIJXo1_400.png))</sub>

See a Java implementation here: http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2009/08/treemap-for-friendfeed.html

Answer (score 3):

this solution should work:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
MyFrame(Image images[])
 {
 JTabbedPane tabbed= new JTabbedPane();
 setContentPane(tabbed);
 for(int i=0;i< images.length;++i)
  {
  tabbed.addTab("Image "+i, new JScrollPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(images[i]))));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Actually this makes a lot more sense than my answer, so +1

Comment: @Pierre, I didn't say that in my question, but the user should be able to see all the images at same time. I'm not shure this can be done with a JTabbedPane. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use [JInternalFrame](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) for this, you can drag the pictures around and change the size, too.